# Publishing Poetry

Tags: publishing, poetry

(I searched combined tags for publishing & poetry, and only found a few older questions, detailed below.)

So - Spring 2019 - **where do poets publish now?**  Is it all self-publish, have the few magazines mentioned in the past gone away, are any new markets appearing? Are anthologies the best new thing?

If suggesting searches on a submission-info site, can you please verify it's free, and share results from (like I'll demonstrate below on my Submission Grinder Answer.)

---

**Updates of**
[Where to publish poems?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/4855/where-to-publish-poems) (2012 - and poetry.com is a known scammer)
[Is there a Market for Poetry with a Fixed Verse Form](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/251/is-there-a-market-for-poetry-with-a-fixed-verse-form) (2011)
[Lists of Suggested Magazines to Submit To](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/19/lists-of-suggested-magazines-to-submit-to) (2010)

Not a duplicate of [A Market For Long Narrative Poetry?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/40839/a-market-for-long-narrative-poetry?rq=1) (2018) because it focuses on one specific type of (looong) poem and I intend for this to be a more general question

Not a duplicate of [Do publishers prefer a particular type of poem?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/16810/do-publishers-prefer-a-particular-type-of-poem) (2015) because that question was more asking what publishers want, not what publishers are there.

Comment: I have an answer below discussing Poets & Writers but want to comment on Duotrope (since it isn't free, it doesn't meet your exact criteria but may still be useful. Duotrope runs about $5 per month. It lists thousands of journals and publishers. It has a pretty decent search system, includes stats on how long it takes for publishers to respond, let's you track your submissions, and more. I've used it for years and find it very useful.

Answer (score 4):

I ran a search on **Submission Grinder**, Poetry, Paid.

https://thegrinder.diabolicalplots.com/Search/ByFilter?poetry=true

It came up with 109 results, but almost half had no-data on response time, so they might not still be around. (Or SG users may not submit a lot of poetry.)

Disclaimer: I have never submitted poetry anywhere, and except for Margaret Atwood, I rarely read any.

**Here are some of the markets with the fastest turnaround time**:
*Note: The Submission Grinder overview link includes a link to the actual journal/site in question, direct to their submission guidelines.

- [*The Christian Science Monitor*](https://thegrinder.diabolicalplots.com/Market/Index?id=7557&pid=undefined) focuses on positive, short poetry.
- [*Poets Respond*](https://thegrinder.diabolicalplots.com/Market/Index?id=8726&pid=undefined) - a smaller section of a journal publishing poetic
  responses to news of the past week. No length/tone limits.
- [*50 Haikus*](https://thegrinder.diabolicalplots.com/Market/Index?id=2918&pid=undefined) has a clear type they want.
- [*Threepenny Review*](https://thegrinder.diabolicalplots.com/Market/Index?id=5890&pid=undefined) has a
  specific submission window. They appear to pay $200 per poem.
- [*Journal of Compressed Arts*](https://thegrinder.diabolicalplots.com/Market/Index?id=8413&pid=undefined) - submission windows, pays $50 -
  under 20 lines or 75 words

Answer (score 4):

*[Writer's Digest](https://www.writersdigest.com/)* is still chugging away with their Writer's Market series.  With more specialities than ever.  I found the 2018 (though the 2019 one is out) [Poet's Market](https://www.writersdigestshop.com/poet-s-market-2019-ebook-r8473) on [Hoopla](https://www.hoopladigital.com/).  (Hoopla is a repository of e-books and movies available for free if your library subscribes to it...you don't keep them, you check out up to 10 titles a month.)

You can't do any searches (except the usual type in an e-book) but it's the best collection of publishers, magazines, contests, and more for the American market (and is perhaps the best for other English-speaking countries).

You can also find paper copies of these books at your local library, usually in the reference section (which means you can't check them out, but this varies).  Or of course you can purchase a paper or electronic copy.  Older ones are still valuable and you can sometimes get them for a song at a used bookstore when the new ones come out.

So take some time and go through the book.  There are articles on many aspects of writing and publishing poetry and it talks about the latest market trends.  Then go through the listings and pull some that matter.  It takes more time than using a specialized search engine, but it will be more comprehensive.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not posting the results of this query because I don't have the time to copy, format, etc. The Poets & Writers site [Poets & Writers](https://www.pw.org) has information available under the "Publish Your Writing" tab. It has a rudimentary search and since I searched on just "poetry" and "simultaneous submissions" the list went on for many pages. You may be able to trim this down some. Unlike Duotrope, PW is free. They do give you some good info on the different journals.

Answer (score 2):

Many poets, particularly if they are slam poets, or otherwise connected to live poetry audiences, **self-publish "chapbooks"** which can be easily and cheaply constructed from several sheets of letter-sized paper (folded in half, and stapled down the middle, with a sheet of heavier bond paper or cardstock for the cover).  Able to be produced yourself in a copyshop, and typically sold for around $5, these can be an effective and (mildly) remunerative way of disseminating your poetry to an audience.

As with most self-publishing projects, **your sales will be determined by your own salespersonship**.  If you read frequently in public, and especially if you tour as a poet, this can be a very good option.  A good percentage of the work I own by living poets is in chapbook form.

Also, as is true for any self-publishing project, **particularly strong sales could pave the way for eventual reprinting** or re-collection by a conventional publisher (although probably it would need to comprise poems from several chapbooks).